# How to get the 'photoreference' of places for google Photo References API

Tags: google-api, google-photos

I am using Google Places API for getting photos from location.. I got the API call and is working correctly. But my question is how to get the `photoreference` key for a location..

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&**photoreference=CoQBegAAAFg5U0y-iQEtUVMfqw4KpXYe60QwJC-wl59NZlcaxSQZNgAhGrjmUKD2NkXatfQF1QRap-PQCx3kMfsKQCcxtkZqQ**&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyCAe7UnfJ6NA9vFkBpswQK1udVzivRdLD0
```

**photoreference=CoQBegAAAFg5U0y-iQEtUVMfqw4KpXYe60QwJC-wl59NZlcaxSQZNgAhGrjmUKD2NkXatfQF1QRap-PQCx3kMfsKQCcxtkZqQ**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the photo reference from the `Place Search` or `Place Details` request. Details are at : https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/photos